# Vampire Bloodlines Can't be nice to Nines as a Ventrue

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

I've tried everything after meeting Nines the first time, but I always offend Nines in the end. I think there are some conversation options missing for me, but I don't know why. For example the following conversation option seem to be missing: "Have you tried meeting with the Camarilla?" and "One more question. Any advice you can give me?". Instead I only can say: "I think the command structure of your group leaves a lot to be desired."

I was using the following video to compare it:

I'm playing with unofficial patch 9.2.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I didn't find anything with google to help me with this problem. I go to meet him immediately after he saves me from some guys.

Comment: Well, Ventrue *do* tend to be the stuck-up hierarchy-obsessed assholes of the Clans...

Answer (score 3):

It might be that your Humanity is low. The amount of points concerning Humanity in the game will influence your conversations with others, as you will be ruder and more defiant with cooperation. Keep track of your Humanity, the more points you have, the nicer you are. That's why Toreadors are nicer and more humane, as they get double points in Humanity every time they do a good act. They are more in tune with people, and are less likely to turn into the Beast than other clans.